# What does initializing the arrays to -1 do exactly?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is the description of the function prototype that I am supposed to create for a checkers game

### CountJumps

1. Your function CountJumps has the prototype

   ```
   int CountJumps( int CMCheckersBoard[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE],
   int numRowsInBoard, int player, int xLocArray[], int yLocArray[] );
   ```
2. Your function CountJumps considers all of one player’s pieces.  The integer player distinguishes which player’s checkers are being considered.  When called with player = 1 CountJumps considers the white players checkers. When called with player = 2 CountJumps considers the read player’s checkers.
3. All elements of arrays  yLocArray[] and xLocArray[] are initialized to  -1 at the start of each call to CountJumps. After the initialization the first unused element in each of the arrays is location 0.
4. One by one each of the squares on the board are examined.  For each square containing one of the player’s checkers

   a.      Function IsJump is called to determine if  the player’s checker on square CMCheckersBoard[yindex][xindex]   can jump an opponent’s piece.  If it can:

   1. The counter recording the number of the player’s checkers that can jump is incremented
   2. The value of xindex is placed in the next unused location of array xLocArray and the value of yindex is placed in the next unused element of array yLocArray.
5. Your function CountJumps returns an integer which contains the number of the player’s checkers that can jump an opponent’s checker.

In my main function, I have these arrays and variables initialized and declared:

```
int main ()
{
    //Declare Arrays and variables
    int myCMCheckersBoard[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
    int xIndicesMove[MAX_PIECES];
    int yIndicesMove[MAX_PIECES];
    int xIndicesJump[MAX_PIECES];
    int yIndicesJump[MAX_PIECES];
    int numRowsInBoard = 0;
    int player = 0;
```

I understand that the function will be called using:

```
CountJumps(myCMCheckersBoard, numRowsInBoard, player, xIndicesJump, yIndicesJump);
```

But I have no idea how to start the prototype.

1. I don't know what initializing the arrays to -1 would do and what it would mean
2. Not sure if the function, IsJump, will be called within this function

I simply need a good hint on how to start.

Please ask if any clarification is needed :)

```
for (yindex=0; yindex < numRowsInBoard; yindex++)
{
    for (xindex=0; xindex < numRowsInBoard;xindex++)
    {
        xLocArray[xindex] = -1;
        yLocArray[yindex] = -1;
    }
}
```

Would this be correct for initializing? If so, what is my next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is initializing

"Initializing" means something like "starting as being". All elements of array `yLocArray`and `xLocArray` should start as being `-1`.

### Initializing an array

Initializing the array itself to `-1` makes little sense, as in `C` and `C++` arrays are read-only references (`&array == array` is true), and not writable values (`array = NULL` gives an error), much like functions.

---

You can initialize array *elements* as follows:

#### Using array initializer

To initialize all elements in an array to 0, you can use `array[SIZE] = { 0 };`.
For any other value, you will have to use an explicit initializer: `array[SIZE] = { 1, 1, 1, ..., 1 }`.

#### Using a loop

For more complicated types, you'll often find yourself having to use a loop.

```
#include <cstdlib> // size_t

int array[SIZE];

for (std::size_t i=0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    array[i] = -1;
}
```

#### Using templates

In C++, but not C, you will be able to rewrite the above as such:

```
#include <algorithm> // fill_n

int array[SIZE];

std::fill_n(array, SIZE, -1);
```

#### Using memset

You could also use `memset` on a two's complement systems:

```
#include <cstring> // memset

...

std::memset(array, -1, sizeof(int)*SIZE);
```

This is not recommended, faster than a conventional `for` loop.

---

Note: It's useful to `#define` the following macros in your program:

```
/**
 * The `sizeof` an element in array 'arr'.
 */
#define ELEMSIZE(arr) sizeof(*arr)
/**
 * The number of elements in array 'arr'.
 */
#define ARRAYSIZE(arr) sizeof(arr)/ELEMSIZE(arr)
```

Comment: for (yindex=0; yindex < numRowsInBoard; yindex++)
 {
  for (xindex=0; xindex < numRowsInBoard;xindex++)
  {
   xLocArray[xindex] = -1;
   yLocArray[yindex] = -1;
  }
 }
 would this be correct?

Comment: @PikAleex It would be 'correct' in the sense that it achieves your goal. It would very much _not_ be 'correct' because the inner loop runs `numRowsInBoard*(numRowsInBoard-1)` times too much (A _big_ number, even for 8 row's that's already `8*7=56` times too much). `for (std::size_t x=0; x < numRowsInBoard; x++) { xLocArray[x] = -1; yLocArray[x] = -1; }` would achieve the exact same goal without the need for an inner loop.